# Horizontal ScrollView not working in React Native Expo

Tags: android, react-native, expo

My code is pretty simple, structure looks like this. It's all nested inside of a Stack.Navigator screen with gestures enabled. Disabling gestures makes it work as it should, but gestures don't affect iOS.

```
<ScrollView nestedScrollEnabled={true} horizontal={true}>
    <Image source={{height:200,width:200,uri:"someuri"}}/>
    <Image source={{height:200,width:200,uri:"someuri"}}/>
    <Image source={{height:200,width:200,uri:"someuri"}}/>
    <Image source={{height:200,width:200,uri:"someuri"}}/>
    <Image source={{height:200,width:200,uri:"someuri"}}/>
</ScrollView>
```

That's it. For some reason this works perfectly on web and iOS but not Android. I really don't understand why . My images load perfectly. I added nestedScrollEnabled to see if it fixed anything but it didn't.